# Cleaning dataset based on a reference file

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean **data_set** by replacing some values for some variables with the new values which is included in the **Changes_file** after matching the ID and the variable name.

The ID is unique in the data_set but it could be duplicated in the changes_file

Example:

```
> data_set = data.frame(ID = c('20','22','25','60','40','44'), Gender = c('Female','Female','Female','Male','Male','Male'), Age = c('41','45','50','52','36','61'))

> data_set
  ID Gender Age
1 20 Female  41
2 22 Female  45
3 25 Female  50
4 60   Male  52
5 40   Male  36
6 44   Male  61

> Changes_file = data.frame(ID = c('22','22','60','40'), Variables = c('Gender','Age','Age','Gender'), New_Information  = c('Male','50','17','Female'))
> Changes_file
  ID Variables New_Information
1 22    Gender            Male
2 22       Age              50
3 60       Age              17
4 40    Gender          Female
```

The result is expected to be:

```
> data_set_new
  ID Gender Age
1 20 Female  41
2 22   Male  50
3 25 Female  50
4 60   Male  17
5 40 Female  36
6 44   Male  61
```

The data I am working on has more than 10,000 rows and more than 300 variables, and I just mentioned a simple example above.

I appreciate any advice or suggestions for this process and especially for the 'matching' part.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this by pivoting your changes data so it's the same structure as the original data and then using a couple `rows_*` operations:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

changes_wide = Changes_file |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Variables, values_from = New_Information)

common_cols = intersect(names(changes_wide), names(data_set))

changes_wide |>
  ## "patch" the changes file first so the NAs don't overwrite 
  ## non-missing values
  rows_patch(y = data_set[common_cols], by = "ID", unmatched = "ignore") |>
  ## then update the original with the patched changes
  rows_update(x = data_set, by = "ID")
#   ID Gender Age
# 1 20 Female  41
# 2 22   Male  50
# 3 25 Female  50
# 4 60   Male  17
# 5 40 Female  36
# 6 44   Male  61
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply; as the data is much larger this message appears when using the code you shared:"Error in `rows_patch()`:
! All columns in `y` must exist in `x`, could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Just added a line to select the common columns.

Comment: Thanks again; the error message now is: rows_patch()`: ! Can't convert `y$Q2 <double> to match type of `x$Q2 ` <character>. Could please suggest anything to solve it?

Comment: Yeah, make sure your `Q2` columns are the same class in both `changes_wide` and `data_set`. Convert `changes_wide` to match` data_set`, probably.

Comment: Thank you, It is fixed but unfortunately, a new message appears: Error in UseMethod("rows_update", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'rows_update' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Sounds like you changed a whole data set to `character` class rather than just a column. If you continue to have trouble, I'd suggest asking a new question, sharing enough sample data to reproduce any problems you're having. Going one-error-at-a-time in comments without sharing data to reproduce problems or seeing the code you're running is a very tiresome way work.

Comment: I fixed them, and the code is working; many thanks!